# Xilinx System Generator Pulse Compression

Tags: fpga, xilinx, system-generator

I am making a system generator model for radar pulse compression using HW Cosimulation of Spartan 6.

On internet there are three research papers which are close to what I want to find.

You can see the models in research paper.

Two are using FIR filter for time domain compression and third one is using FFT for freq domain compression, but I can't complete the whole model and generate FIR or FFT using Core gen.

So can someone help me realize the model please? Otherwise if someone has previously worked on it and can provide me with the model files, that would be really helpful.

PS. I have almost completed the time domain model but I do not know how to find out the coefficients of FIR filter.

Thank You. Anxiously waiting for reply.

The link to three research papers are on another site where i asked the same question. I hope admin do not disapprove.
http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/DSP-Tools/Pulse-Compression/m-p/404871#M7586

Comment: I think your question is more suited for [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have posted there also but no one seems to know :(